# how do do subtype() to tuple in flink cep?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

```
Pattern< Tuple3< String, String, String >, ? > pattern = Pattern.<Tuple3< String, String, String > > begin( "start" )            
            .next( "3" ).where( new FilterFunction< Tuple3< String, String, String > >() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter ( Tuple3< String, String, String > value ) throws Exception {
                    return value.f2.equals( "3" );
                }
            } )
            .next( "4" ).subtype(Tuple.getTupleClass( 2 )).where( new FilterFunction< Tuple2< String, String> >() {
                @Override
                public boolean filter ( Tuple2< String, String > value ) throws Exception {
                    return value.f1.equals( "3" );
                }
            } )
```

subtype(Tuple.getTupleClass( 2 )),and occoured the error
`Inferred type 'capture<? extends org.apapche.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple>' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound;should extend 'org.apapche.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3<java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String>'`

should I modify this?but how?`Pattern< Tuple3< String, String, String >, ? > pattern`

---

update by 2017012

```
JoinedStreams< Tuple2< String, String >, Tuple3< String, String, String > >.Where< String >.EqualTo
        joinedStreams = someStream
        .join( otherStream )
        .where( value -> value.f1 )
        .equalTo( value -> value.f1 );

Pattern< Tuple, ? > pattern = Pattern.< Tuple > begin( "start" )
        .subtype( Tuple3.class )
        .where( evt -> evt.f2.equals( "3" ) )
        .next( "4" )
        .subtype( Tuple2.class )
        .where( evt -> evt.f1.equals( "3" ) )
        .within( Time.seconds( 10 ) );

PatternStream< ...> patternStream = CEP.pattern( joinedStreams, pattern );
```

I tried this, and don't what should I fill in `PatternStream< ...>`.Thanks for anyone who can offer help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Pattern<Tuple, ?> pattern =
    Pattern.<Tuple>begin("start")
    .next("3")
        .subtype(Tuple3.class)
        .where(new FilterFunction<Tuple3>() {

            @Override
            public boolean filter(Tuple3 value) throws Exception {
                return value.f2.equals("3");
            }
        })
    .next("4")
        .subtype(Tuple2.class)
        .where(new FilterFunction<Tuple2>() {

            @Override
            public boolean filter(Tuple2 value) throws Exception {
                return value.f1.equals("3");
            }
        });
```

Start with a common type `Tuple` and use concrete types `Tuple2` and `Tuple3` for subevents. And a data stream for this pattern must have a `Tuple` type.

Comment: Thanks very much ,I'll try it and latter give you a reply.Another question is that can I join another stream in flink CEP?cuz `CEP.pattern( partitionedEventA, pattern );` you can only pass only one DataStream to it.The Tuple2 in my questino is from another DataStream.But I dont not how to do that.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
    Pattern<Tuple, ?> pattern = Pattern.<Tuple>begin("start")
            .subtype(Tuple3.class)
            .where(evt -> evt.f2.equals("3"))
            .next("4")
            .subtype(Tuple2.class)
            .where(evt -> evt.f1.equals("3"))
            .within(Time.seconds(10));
```

1. you needn't add next after begin
2. notice subtype's literal meaning, tuple3 and tuple2 should extend tuple.

If you want to connect two different datastreams.

```
DataStream<Tuple2> someStream = //...
DataStream<Tuple3> otherStream = //...

ConnectedStreams<Tuple2, Tuple3> connectedStreams = someStream.connect(otherStream);
```

Then you can use CoMap, CoFlatMap to get the same type, for example transform Tuple2, Tuple3 to String:
ConnectedStreams → DataStream

```
connectedStreams.flatMap(new CoFlatMapFunction<Tuple2, Tuple3, String>() {

   @Override
   public void flatMap1(Integer value, Collector<String> out) {
       out.collect(Tuple2.toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void flatMap2(String value, Collector<String> out) {
       for (String word: value.split(" ")) {
         out.collect(Tuple3.toString);
       }
   }
});
```

Here are some useful links, introducing a good use case:

1. [Introducing Complex Event Processing (CEP) with Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/news/2016/04/06/cep-monitoring.html)
2. [Chinese version that I translate](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000008074156)

Comment: thank you very much,so how can I express this:a Tuple2 followed by Tuple3?

Comment: Thanks very much.Another question is that can I join another stream in flink CEP?cuz in `CEP.pattern( partitionedEventA, pattern );` you can only pass only one DataStream to it.The Tuple2 in my questino is from another DataStream.But I dont not how to do that.Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but it is related with DataStream. U can connect two DataStream. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. But if I want to join fields in someStream and otherStream .like someStream.FieldB==otherStream.FieldE . Should I use joinedStream ? But I don't know how to write the where clause.Thanks very much again.and Can I add your qq ?this is my number:245915794

Comment: Of course, u can. Just use select API on  PatternStream. See Chinese Version Link: https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000008074156 . If U read through it, U can understand. We're not allowed to use QQ among working time, maybe after work.

Comment: Join is based on window, U need to figure that out. why don't u use connect method?